# Scanner next() throwing NoSuchElementException for some online compilers

Tags: java

This seems be a common question (asked multiple times) yet I'm not able to find an explanation for this behaviour. Following code works in one compiler but throws `Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException` in another compiler

```
  Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter name: ");
  String name = s.next();
  System.out.println("Name is " + name);
```

Tested on https://www.compilejava.net/ and https://www.codechef.com/ide it throws exception. However, on some compilers it works fine. Is there any reason for this behaviour (like change in JDK or something)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read input from the console using the Scanner class in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871520/how-can-i-read-input-from-the-console-using-the-scanner-class-in-java)

Comment: I think the problem is, that these online IDEs doesn't support user input.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This exception gets thrown because there are no more elements in the enumeration.

See [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html):

> Thrown by the nextElement method of an Enumeration to indicate that
>   there are no more elements in the enumeration.

---

Some online IDEs don't allow user input at all, in which case the exception will get thrown as soon as you try to read user input.

1. It works on [TutorialsPoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php) IDE because it allows user input.
2. It doesn't works on [codechef](https://www.codechef.com/ide) and [compilejava](https://www.compilejava.net/) IDEs because these IDEs does not support user input.

However there's secondary way to add user input on codechef. Just tick mark on `Custom Input` checkbox and provide any input. It will then compile.

[image]

---

Another reason for this exception, i.e. there simply not being more user input, can be handled by, before calling `s.next()`, just checking `s.hasNext()` to see whether the scanner has another token.

```
  Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.print("Enter name: ");
  String name = null;
  if(s.hasNext())
      name = s.next();
  System.out.println("Name is " + name);
```

Answer (score 1):

According to rD. answer another solution for the problem would be catching the exception:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter name: ");
String name = "";
try {
    name = s.next();
    System.out.println("Name is " + name);
} catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
    System.out.println("You have to enter a name");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should enter your input in specified area for it while working on online IDEs. As you have given the example `codechef` has extra field for the input(i.e. custom input). But some of online IDEs don't support custom input as in your first linked IDE. They give error. (i.e. `java.util.NoSuchElementException`)

[image]