# Having a NoSuchElementException and I couldn't find how to fix that

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I have written some code for a word guessing game. It reads a character from user input and searches that character in a word; depending on whether the character is in the word or not, the program returns and controls some variables.

Here's the code:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Character;

public class Game {

    private String word;
    private int wordNum;
    private char[] wordinArr = new char[30];
    private char[] wordinDashes = new char[30];
    private int lettersFound = 0;
    int numOfGuesses=10;

    public Game() {

        Random random = new Random();   //επιλογή τυχαίας λέξης
        wordNum = random.nextInt(120);
        //System.out.println("Random Number: "+wordNum);
        word = Lexicon.getWord(wordNum);
        //System.out.println(word); 
    } 

    public void startTheGame() {

        do {


            wordinArr = word.toCharArray();
            System.out.println(wordinArr);
            System.out.println(word.length());
            for(int i=0;i<word.length();i++) 
                wordinDashes[i]='-';
            System.out.println("The random word is now: ");
            System.out.println(wordinDashes);
            System.out.println("You have  "+numOfGuesses+" guesses left.");

            if(MakeATry())
                numOfGuesses-=1;
        }while(numOfGuesses !=0 && lettersFound!=word.length());

        if(lettersFound==word.length())
            System.out.println("Congratulations! You guessed the word: "+word);
        else {
            System.out.println("Unfortunately you didn't find the word. The word was"+word);
            System.out.println("Try again to find the next word!");
        }
    }


    public boolean MakeATry() {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Your guess: ");
        char guess = input.next().charAt(0);

        if(Character.isLowerCase(guess)){            
            char temp = Character.toUpperCase(guess);
            guess = temp;
        }

        for(int i=0;i<word.length();i++) { 
            if(guess==wordinArr[i]) {
                System.out.println("The guess is CORRECT!");
                wordinDashes[i]=guess;
                input.close();
                lettersFound++;
                return true;
            }
        }           
        input.close();
        return false;       
    }

}
```

But when I run it, I always get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException  
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)  
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)  
    at Game.MakeATry(Game.java:54)  
    at Game.startTheGame(Game.java:37)  
    at Main.main(Main.java:17)
```

The line 54 in `MakeATry()` method is that line ->`char guess = input.next().charAt(0);`. I have spent hours trying to figure out how to fix it, but no result. Does anyone has any idea about this error?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: could you please also paste your maln method as well or entire class would be good

Comment: What do you enter into the console?

Comment: Ok, I pasted the entire class which includes the method I have the problem with.

Comment: You need to call Scanner.nextLine() , i.e. in this case input .nextLine(). You aren't advancing to the next line, so you run out of tokens on this line

Comment: @Neo The user must type a chatacter, a letter to be accurate.

Comment: So you don't insert anything?

Comment: As a user, I type a letter and after that the program stops and I have that error

Comment: @Pradeep Where i should call input.nextLine() in order not to have error, because i tried adding it but again the error hasn't been fixed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13729294/nosuchelementexception-with-java-util-scanner can you please have a look at this link

Comment: Yeah of course I will! I am new to all this and I have a lot to learn. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of

```
input.close();
```

use

```
input.reset();
```

Comment: Thanks! I used input.reset(); and I dont have that error anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your program should verify that the user has in fact entered some input. This sounds like the scanner has reached the end of the input (which is, in this case, nothing) and throws an exception because you still want more, as it should.

As stated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39766563/5235921) SO answer, some IDEs do not allow user input, so even if you are entering input, it may not register in your program. Try another IDE or even compiling the whole thing by hand.