# Java Program for Shipments

Tags: java

I am trying to create a Java program that reads in a set of shipments (using Scanner and a while loop), breaking if shipment number is -1 and then rejects and prints each rejected shipment along with an error message if weight is negative or zero or greater than 70 pounds, or if volume is negative or zero or greater than 1000 cubic inches.

I am receiving the following error message when compiling:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
at Shipment.main(Shipment.java:30)
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, here is the code I have now:

```
import java.util.Scanner;  
public class Main {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        int shipmentNumber;  
        double shipmentWeight = 0;  
        double shipmentVolume = 0;  
        double totalWeight = 0;  
        double totalVolume = 0;  
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);  
        while(true) {  
            System.out.println("Enter shipment number: ");  
            shipmentNumber = sc.nextInt();  

            if(shipmentNumber == -1) {  
                break;  
            }  
            System.out.println("Enter shipment weight: ");  
            shipmentWeight = sc.nextDouble();  
            System.out.println("Enter shipment volume: ");  
            shipmentVolume = sc.nextDouble();  
            if(shipmentWeight <= 0 || shipmentWeight > 70) {  
                System.out.println("Shipment " + shipmentNumber + " rejected!!! Weight '" + shipmentWeight + "'pounds is invalid");  
                continue;  
            } else if (shipmentVolume <= 0 || shipmentVolume > 1000) {  
                System.out.println("Shipment " + shipmentNumber + " rejected!!! Volume '" + shipmentVolume + "'cubic inches is invalid");  
                continue;  
            } else {  
                System.out.println("Shipment " + shipmentNumber + " accepted!!!\nWeight: " + shipmentWeight + "pounds  Volume: " + shipmentVolume + "cubic inches");  
            }  

            totalWeight += shipmentWeight;  
            totalVolume += shipmentVolume;  
        }  
        System.out.println("Total shipment weight: " + totalWeight + "pounds");  
        System.out.println("Total shipment volume: " + totalVolume + "cubic inches");  
    }  
}
```

Comment: How are you running it, and what input are you typing?

Comment: it works for me, with entering random numbers.

Comment: compiling with no problem.

Comment: Unfortunately I am having to compile and run in online compilers at the moment and the error shows before I am able to input anything.

Comment: @08state15, mention which online compiler you are using

Comment: https://ideone.com/HxyQ4H this is compiling on online ide too

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scanner next() throwing NoSuchElementException for some online compilers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39766488/scanner-next-throwing-nosuchelementexception-for-some-online-compilers)

Comment: If you can use any online compiler then use this https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_java_compiler    It works there.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments, it seems you re running the program in online editor/compiler.
Most of the online compilers do not expose Standard input and output to end user. So System.in is not available. Run this code locally in your pc and it will run without issues.

Comment: ... or if you have to run it online, don't use `System.in` Create a `StringReader` or something like that as your input for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Would you like to try the code out to an IDE and use some TDD practices to see where is your code broken?
I would change `while (true) {break;}` into `while (shipmentNumber != -1)` and stop using `continue` into the loop, you should simply remove that by using nested `if/else`  or changing the way of doing the loop. However, what is line 30 in your code?

Answer (score -1):

How are you getting that exception on compile? NoSuchElementException is only thrown during runtime.

If you are actually getting the above exception on runtime, then it seems like the input is exhausted and it is unable to assert an integer value before calling nextInt().

Try by following this snippet

```
if(sc.hasNextInt()){
    shipmentNumber = sc.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: There won't be any compiling issues since this is not a compile-time error. This is an exception thrown at runtime.

Comment: i mean running successfuly without throwing any error or exception

Comment: Even i don't see any visible errors in his code, If the exception that he has logged is legit, then the above snippet is something that he should take a look at